# formArray FileUpload using formData

Tags: angular

**when i add formarray file i found file value/data but when i add file list into filArray file add perfectly. but i append that file into formData it shows null.
I already apply that way which i mention below.But it don't work.
If Anyone solve this issue please help me!!!**

```
Component.ts

    import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-apply-assessor-pool',
      templateUrl: './apply-assessor-pool.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./apply-assessor-pool.component.scss']
    })
    export class ApplyAssessorPoolComponent implements OnInit {
      assessorEntryForm: FormGroup;
      industryProofFile: any;
      fileArray:any=[];
      file:any;
    
      @ViewChild('myInput8')
      industryInputVariable8: ElementRef;

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
      ngOnInit() {
        this.assessorEntryForm = this.fb.group({
          industryExpFormArray: this.fb.array([]),
        });
      }
    
      get industryExpFormArray(): FormArray {
        return this.assessorEntryForm.get('industryExpFormArray') as FormArray;
      }
    
      addIndustryExperience(): void {
        let industryExpFormArray = this.assessorEntryForm.get('industryExpFormArray') as FormArray;
        if (industryExpFormArray.length >= 4) {
          this.notification.error(
            'Failed',
            'You can add maximum 4 industry experience !'
          );
          return;
        }
        else {
          industryExpFormArray.push(this.fb.group({
            organization: ["", Validators.required],
            designation: ["", Validators.required],
            occupationName: ["", Validators.required],
            responsibility: ["", Validators.required],
            yearOfService: ["", Validators.required],
            industryProofFile: ["", Validators.required],
          }));
        }
}
      onSelectIndustryFile(event: any, parentIndex: number) {
        const message = this.utilityService.validateInputFile(event.target.files,
          this.allowedPhotoExtensions,
          this.maxFormatPhotoFileSize
        );
        if (message !== '') {
          this.notification.error('error', message);
          this.industryInputVariable8.nativeElement.value = '';
          return;
        }
        const file = event.target.files[0];
    
        const target: DataTransfer = event.target as DataTransfer;
        if (target.files.length !== 1) {
          throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
        }
        this.industryProofFile = file;
    
        if (this.industryProofFile) {
    
          this.industryExpFormArray.at(parentIndex)?.get('industryProofFile')?.setValue(this.industryProofFile);
        }
      }
      
      submitForm(): void {
        for (const key of Object.keys(this.assessorEntryForm.controls)) {
          this.assessorEntryForm.controls[key].markAsDirty();
          this.assessorEntryForm.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
        }
        const formData = new FormData();
        
        this.industryExpFormArray.controls.forEach((item: any) => {
          let obj = item?.value;
          let temp = obj?.industryProofFile;
          this.fileArray.push(temp);
        });
    
        let industryExperienceFormArrayData = [];
    
        industryExperienceFormArrayData = this.assessorEntryForm.controls.industryExpFormArray.value;
    
        formData.append('assessorIndustryList', JSON.stringify(industryExperienceFormArrayData));
      }
    }
```

**Here is my html file. If anyone need to show html. I use NgZorro.**

> html

```
<form>
      <b>Relevant Industry Experiences (start with the latest experience)</b>
      <div class="float-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addIndustryExperience()" type="button">Add Industry Experience (max
          4)</button>

      </div>

      <nz-table *ngIf="industryExpFormArray.controls.length>0" #basicTable [nzData]="industryExpFormArray.controls"
        [nzFrontPagination]="false">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sl.</th>
            <th>Name of Organization</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Occupation/Field</th>
            <th>Responsibilities</th>
            <th>Years of Service/ Experience</th>
            <th>Proof Document</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <ng-container formArrayName="industryExpFormArray">
            <tr *ngFor="let item of industryExpFormArray?.controls; let parentIndex = index;">
              <ng-container [formGroupName]="parentIndex">
                <td>{{parentIndex+1}}</td>
                <td>
                  <nz-form-item>
                    <nz-form-control nzHasFeedback nzValidatingTip="Validating..." [nzErrorTip]="photoFileErrorTpl">
                      <input type="file" nz-input #industryInputVariable8 (change)="onSelectIndustryFile($event,parentIndex)" />
                      <ng-template #photoFileErrorTpl let-control>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">
                          Please select photo!
                        </ng-container>
                      </ng-template>
                    </nz-form-control>
                  </nz-form-item>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
        </tbody>
      </nz-table>
    </form>
```

> image
> [image: I want to upload file using angular formArray using formData]

Comment: You are uploading multiple files, there is problem on how you add the param with an index for file. The format should be like: "industryFills.0", "industryFills.1"...The code should be: `formData.append('industryFills.' + index, this.fileArray[index])`

Comment: formData.append('industryFills.' + index, this.fileArray[index]) i use for demo it can't serve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   onSelectIndustryFile(event: any, parentIndex: number) {
    const message = this.utilityService.validateInputFile(
      event.target.files,
      this.allowedPhotoExtensions,
      this.maxFormatPhotoFileSize
    );
    if (message !== '') {
      this.notification.error('error', message);
      this.industryInputVariable8.nativeElement.value = '';
      return;
    }
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    const target: DataTransfer = event.target as DataTransfer;
    if (target.files.length !== 1) {
      throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    }
    this.industryProofFile = file;
    // this.industryProofFileShow = false;

    if (this.industryProofFile) {
      this.industryExpFormArray.at(parentIndex)?.get('industryProofFile')?.setValue(this.industryProofFile);
    }
    this.getBase64(file).then((response: any) => {
      if (response != null) {
        let fileString = response?.split(',')[1];
        this.industryExpFormArray.at(parentIndex)?.get('industryProofFile')?.setValue(fileString);
      }
    });
  }


     getBase64(file: any) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        })
      }
```